# Determine ruby version from within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-enterprise-edition

Is there a way to determine what version of Ruby is running from within Rails (either on the web or through `script/console`)? I have Ruby 1.8.6 installed but I've also installed Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7-20090928 and want to ensure that it's using the right installation.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Use this global constant:

```
RUBY_VERSION
```

Other relevant global constants include:

```
RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
RUBY_PLATFORM
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE
```

Usage example via `irb` session:

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
```

Answer (score 14):

Try the constant RUBY_VERSION.  I use this extensively to determine whether I'm running under 1.8 or JRuby.

Also, if you're not in production mode, you can do a quick check by hitting the URL "/rails/info/properties"

Answer (score 13):

Use `RUBY_VERSION` as mentioned by others.

You can then use `Gem::Version` to do version string comparison:

```
require 'rubygems' # Only needed for ruby pre-1.9.0 but it's safe for later versions (evaluates to false).
if Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('1.9.0')
    extend DL::Importable                                    
else                                                         
    extend DL::Importer                                      
end
```

Comment: I wish this answer was there -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11819525/322020 -- but I can't move it so I ask you to delete this one and post it there.

Comment: The mention of Gem::Version was very helpful, good addition.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the RUBY_VERSION constant and friends you may also want to check out Config::CONFIG. This hash contains not only the version numbers but also a ton of other useful runtime information, like the path to the binary, the hostname, ...

Comment: thank you, I use 'puts RbConfig.ruby' for ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0 and it return '/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby'