# Programmatically getting FULL Ruby version?

Tags: ruby, version

I know it's possible to get the Ruby version (e.g. "1.9.3") via the `RUBY_VERSION` constant.  However, I want to know how to go about determining the exact version (e.g.: "1.9.3-p0").  The reason is that there is a bug that was not fixed in earlier versions of Ruby 1.9.3 that is working in later versions, and I want some code in a gem I'm working on to account for this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589751/determine-ruby-version-from-within-rails -- (not duplicate! here is Ruby, not Rails) -- but it has pure Ruby answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is a `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL` constant as well. So you can get your version string as

```
"#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"
```

Comment: Note that you should also take alternative Ruby implementations in mind (most importantly JRuby and Rubinius). Those use different versions and patch levels (but try to keep more or less compatible there with MRI) and obviously have different bugs. Generally, it is probably much safer to implement against actual capabilities rather than potentially misleading version strings

Comment: @HolgerJust - I'm trying to test binary string encoding with a YAML adapter, and Psych::YAML had this bug for only some versions of 1.9.3 (see here: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5923).  Normally I would just test `defined?(Encoding)`, but that's not an option since this error would occur in some patch levels and not others.  Any suggestions on a way of testing the capabilities here instead of misleading version strings?

Comment: @HolgerJust is there a way to determine the current implementation?

Comment: @nc. There is a `RUBY_ENGINE` constant which is set by most ruby implementations nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll also point out something I discovered called `RUBY_DESCRIPTION` that is a pretty verbose string.

Comment: @MattHuggins Maybe "test for the bug" here; if it passes the serialization case for the reported bug consider it Capability Enabled. Then the specific bug is being tested for (and hidden / wrapped away in some dark corner) which determines the capabilities instead of the engine or version or patch level.

Answer (score 14):

At least in the newest Ruby (2.3.0), there is also a `RUBY_DESCRIPTION` constant:

```
RUBY_DESCRIPTION
# => "ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]"
```