# Ruby version select/detect in file

Tags: ruby, version

I recently try to fix some bugs of SciRuby, and found that in `extconf.rb` it tries to detect the Ruby version and do different work, like this:

```
if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0'
  hfiles.puts "#define RUBY_2 1"
end

if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.3'
  hfiles.puts "#define OLD_RB_SCAN_ARGS"
end
```

in fact, is there a much better way to implement this? I found this one is weak and not so friendly.

Comment: “I found this one is weak and not so friendly.” How so?

Comment: I think [Here][1] is what you've asked for.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589751/determine-ruby-version-from-within-rails

Comment: @Emu, yes, I know this, but I want to ask for a better implementation of determination.

Comment: @Emu, I think that your link formatting only works for q's and a's.  See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's "weak" and it's pretty clear, although the more common way would be to use trailing conditionals...

```
hfiles.puts "#define RUBY_2 1"         if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0'
hfiles.puts "#define OLD_RB_SCAN_ARGS" if RUBY_VERSION <  '1.9.3'
```

It'll work exactly the same, but it's more compact.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an accurate of comparing a version number ('2.0.0' > '2.0' => true)

Comment: Good point, @eradman the answer should be edited to use Gem::Version.new or something similar.  Feel free to edit or I'll do it myself later.

Comment: I have used RUBY_VERSION[0..2].to_f > 2.0 to detect the major version, but I don't know of a clean way to express the concept of < 1.9.3

Comment: This stack overflow addresses this... note the very popular answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051229/how-to-compare-versions-in-ruby